# How do I return other threads in a block in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to access other threads in the same block and I want to return some. I'd like to do something like this:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void returnKernel()
{
    if (blockIdx.x == threadIdx.x)
    {
        //exit/return thread 1
    }
}

int main()
{
    returnKernel<<<4, 4>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of "killing" other running threads, they need to "surrender" themselves. Here is the code from your question modified to exit from thread 1:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void returnKernel()
{
    if (blockIdx.x < blockDim.x && threadIdx.x == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    returnKernel<<<4, 4>>>();
    return 0;
}
```